# Changing Layout Dynamically in Android

Tags: android, layout, dynamic

I have an activity which loads a few layouts in a layout.xml file. The First LinearLayout host the all the views together. The second linear layout hosts  two labels together. The Relative layout host a few labels and a ListView that populates items when loaded. I want to improve navigation by achieving a "TRANSITION" of the RelativeLayout to another Layout without affecting other layouts in the activity. In other words, when clicking on one of the rows populated by the ListView (OnItemClickListener), this event listener replaces the current RelativeLayout with a new Layout.

Any idea of achieving this?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:background="#FFDECE"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Gang Code"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEmpyName"
                ....

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvATRDisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) for that. And use [setDisplayedChild(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html#setDisplayedChild%28int%29) to display particular layout i.e. child

e.g.

```
setDisplayChild(0);
```